# Firebase Authentication Succeed but user can't login

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

An user report that it can't login on our APP

1. The user has created its account with a page registration on our APP
   email: bonheur@mailinator.com
   `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`
2. One minute later, the user goes to the login page, apparently the APP has received a user ID but the account has not been created. I can say that because we have saved the UID in our database.
3. The user tried to register again then it worked fine, same email different user ID has been received. If the user has been created in first place. Firebase would have say: "User Already Exists"

Do you know why the APP has received an user ID but the user has not been created at all?

Thanks

Alain

Comment: There must some `error` in the flow for the user that didn't allow the completion of the process and `returned` at some point.

Comment: We will need to see the code doing this to be able to help you.